# USB-C Connection (Hub) with power to both sides

Tags: usb, hub

I have a Lenovo Miix 720, which has a single USB-C port through which it gets power.  I want to attach an AOC I1601FWUX, which is a USB-C portable monitor.  If I use a straight-through USB-C cable, the laptop powers the monitor and I have no way to power the laptop.  That setup won't last long before I have to recharge the laptop.

What I need is a powered hub that has at least two USB-C ports (I think Gen 1 is good enough) and that can deliver power to both.  Haven't found one yet.  Anyone know of such a hub?

Answer (score 2):

The [Arc Hub](https://bourgedesign.com/collections/all) can supposedly do this, but it's expensive, as such hubs are still relatively new.

Comment: No, this does not do what I need.  It has 2 USB-C ports and does not get its power another way.  So I cannot power the hub and make a connection between two USB-C devices, powering those two devices from the hub.